# Why do moving lines become fuzzy on my monitor?

Tags: display, lcd, visual-artifacts

I recently got a new [notebook](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Medion-Akoya-P6630-MD-89560-Notebook.46769.0.html). With moving images there are some graphical issues, and I'd like to know what causes them. None of my earlier monitors exhibited similar issues.

Moving high contrast lines become jagged, similar to interleaved videos. When moving a horizontal line vertically those artifacts are colored, when moving a vertical line horizontally they aren't colored. The effect isn't observable in static images. And when moving faster the zone in which it occurs becomes wider.

The effect is very visible if I move a window around on the borders of the window and wherever high contrast lines appear. But it appears when watching videos too.

[image: Image replicating the effect]

The vertical line in that image moves to the right, the horizontal line upwards.  This is no screenshot but manually drawn to replicate a similar effect to what was observed. It does not show up in screenshots.

---

The effect is most likely related to the fact that each real pixel consists of different sub-pixels for the different color channels.

But how are these causing the observed effect? Is the change at which the different colors change to the destination brightness different?

The optical impression is that every second pixel in a chess board like arrangement is adapting slower than it's neighbors. But that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I would say that if your screen doesn't show the fuzzy lines, it maybe due to your monitor settings or problem with the display drivers. 

Try changing the refresh rate, or updating display driver.

Oh anther thing....

If it doesn't show on screenshots then it has to be a monitor problem.

Hope this help!

Comment: No it does not show up in screenshots, the image I posted is something I drew trying to replicate the effect. I think it's just a quirk of that notebook display. So I don't think I can fix it. But I'm still interested in why this phenomenon occurs. There must be a reason why this monitor has this problem and no other LCD I've worked with so far.

Comment: Then i think it's the monitors refresh rate. Try changing them this happens when refresh is set between 60-70 in old monitors.

Comment: The refresh rate is set to 60, and there are no other rates to choose from.

Comment: I have seen an effect similar to this when the display resolution is set to something other than the native resolution of the monitor. Alternatively, it could be that the monitor hardware isn't able to keep up with the rate at which the pixels are being asked to change.

Comment: Was it the laptop’s built-in monitor that had/has the problem or an external monitor?

Comment: I wonder if this Web page might explain what you're seeing:  http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/inversion.php